# Geolocation class is not working

Tags: geolocation, commerce-cloud, b2b-commerce

I'm trying to use the Geolocation class and trying to get the Longitude value of my current location. But I'm getting null always. I came to know from the documentation that I'll need to enable **Geolocation tracking feature** for this, otherwise method will always return null. Anyone knows that what is **Geolocation tracking feature** and from where can I enable it. I'm not finding any more information about enabling it in the documentation.

Code that I'm using here is as follows:

```
<isscript>
    var location = dw.util.Geolocation;
    var zipCode = location.getLongitude();
</isscript>
<div id="ShippingOptionsList" class="ShippingOptionsList">
            <p id='zipCode'> ${zipCode} 
                ${location}
            </p>
        </div>
```

Comment: do write back if you had any luck?

Comment: Hi @pkamathk please try `${request.getGeolocation().postalCode}` in ISML. This will give you zipcode of your current location